# I need to change mat-button-toogle to radio button?

Tags: angular

Hi I am new to angular I need to change the below code to radio button.

```html
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="label-icon"><label><b>Certfication Required</b></label>

    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-button-toggle-group aria-label="cert req" name="certification" [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq">
            <mat-button-toggle [value]="true" [disableRipple]="true">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" [disableRipple]="true">No</mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
    </div>

</div>
```

Need to add a input box for certification version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your toggle-group code like below,

```
<div>
   <mat-radio-group aria-label="cert req" name="certification" 
      [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq">
     <mat-radio-button [value]="true">Yes</mat-radio-button>
     <mat-radio-button [value]="false">No</mat-radio-button>
   </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you .html:

```
<label class="radio-group">Certification</label>
<mat-radio-group class="radio" color="primary">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
    <mat-radio-button class="radio-button col-md-3"  [value]="option.value">{{option.name}}</mat-radio-button>
  </ng-container>
</mat-radio-group>
```

In your .ts:

```
options = [{name: 'Yes', value: '1'}, {name: 'No', value: '0'}]
```